# Teams Tab app with SSO and SharePoint Redirection via teamslogon.aspx

Tags: microsoft-teams, spfx

I have Teams app with SSO settings in manifest like this

```
"webApplicationInfo": {
        "id": "25a08858-151f-477d-8fff-e72c9254ac22",
        "resource": "api://abc.com/25a08858-151f-477d-8fff-e72c9254ac22" 
        
    },
```

but I cant redirect app to specific SharePoint site using teamslogon page as below .is there any solution for this ?

```
https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?spfx=true&dest=/sites/myNewSite
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually done this, so it's just an idea, but you probably need to have your .sharepoint.com domain listed in the `validDomains` section of your manifest for this to work.